# react-native onPanResponderMove strange behavior no documentation Animated.Event

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-animated

I have noticed in react-native panResponder onPanResponderMove method calls when I use

```
  onPanResponderMove: Animated.event([null, {dx: this._pan}]),
```

but when I try to use:

```
  onPanResponderMove: (e, gestureState) => {
    Animated.event([null, {dx: this._pan}])
  },
```

the method does't call.
Is there another javascript syntax I can use so that I have a function scope I can use along side Animated.event

Answer (score 3):

Animated.event() returns a function. If you want to run the function, you have to call it. I'm assuming your use case is that you want to execute some actions on every move? In that case, the syntax you are looking for is:

```
onPanResponderMove: (e, gestureState) => {
    ...some actions...
    Animated.event([null, {dx: this.state.pan.x}])(e, gestureState);
  },
```

Comment: This is correct, the above u/fcFn is wrong like u/dazweeja pointed out. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do something along with Animated.event, you need to pass event arguments like so:

```
onPanResponderMove: (e, gestureState) => {
    ...some actions...
    Animated.event([null, {dx: this._pan}])(e, gestureState);
  },
```

This is because **a call to `Animated.event` returns another function** (using provided mappings to bind event data to component variables, so it could call `setValue` on them), which is in turn called back by `onPanResponderMove` listener on the move event.

Comment: You have created a self-executing function where your 'some actions' will run only on PanResponder.create(). In most cases this is only on component mount. My understanding is that the OP would like to run some actions "along side Animated.event" in his code, ie. every time onPanResponderMove is called.